# Cannot display continuous data from sensor after conversion-Python

Tags: python

I have written a code to give me water level in terms of percentage.The `water_level` variable gives the channel display in continuous form.[image]

I am trying to display this data in terms of percentage in continuous form.
However,after callibration it does not display any value.

Here is my code:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import Adafruit_ADS1x15
import datetime

GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
adc=Adafruit_ADS1x15.ADS1115()
while True:
  water_level=(adc.read_adc(0,2)) #Read Water Channel A0
   #Minimum Water Level = 150
   #Maximum Water Level = 32767
 # water_level1 = water_level

  callibrated_water_level= water_level/32617*100

  try:
    print  "Time : ",time.time(),"  ", "Water Level: " ,callibrated_water_level , " % "

  except Exception as e:
     print( e)
     time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Don't catch the exception and you will be able to see what type of error is happening

Comment: @GabrielBenCompte nope it gives no error.

Comment: It stills displays 0 % though.

Comment: Try changing callibrated_water_level= water_level/32617*100 to callibrated_water_level= water_level//32617*100